# How to query table by non primary key attribute in Amazons DynamoDB with DocumentClient.get

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I seem to be having a lot of difficulty querying data with AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient().get().

I am using Serverless and set up my `serverless.yml` with this schema:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ShortUrlsTable:
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: longUrl
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: shortPath
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: longUrlIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: longUrl
                KeyType: HASH
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
          - IndexName: shortPathIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: shortPath
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.tableName}
```

What I want to be able to do is search the DB for a `shortUrlItem` using either `longUrl` or `shortPath`.

So far I have this set up:

```
dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

app.get("/:longUrl", (req, res) => {
  const {longUrl} = req.params

  const getParams = {
    TableName: SHORT_URLS_TABLE,
    Key: {longUrl},
  }

  dynamoDb.get(getParams, (error, result) => {
    res.send({...error, ...result})
  })
})
```

All I seem to be getting is this error message returned to me:

```
"message":"The provided key element does not match the schema","code":"ValidationException","time":"2018-08-17T20:39:27.765Z","requestId":"4RKNVG7ET1ORVF10H71M7AUABRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":21.513795782119505,"TableName":"short-urls-table-dev"
```

I cannot seem to figure out if I am querying correctly or setting up my schema correctly for the secondary index to be the searchable key in my table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two mistakes

**1**: your getParams are wrong. You make `get` request on PK but you provide GSI key in the params section. It should be like

```
const getParams = {
  TableName: SHORT_URLS_TABLE,
  Key: {
    id: id, // Because id is the attribute of your HASH key. 
  }
}
```

This is the reason of the error. Your hash key is not on attribute longUrl.

**2**: Anyway, you can't make `get` request on GSI. Its not have GSI's are designed. GSI does not force uniqueness so there can be multiple items in the same GSI Hash key, therefore you can only `query` instead of `get`.

What you are trying to do is something like

```
const queryParams = {
    TableName: SHORT_URLS_TABLE,
    IndexName: 'longUrlIndex',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'longUrl = :longUrlValue',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      'longUrlValue': longUrl
    }
};

dynamoDb.query(queryParams, (error, result) => {
  res.send({...error, ...result})
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I will give that a try and see what it does, I found a solution similar to the one you gave but it was still suggesting I could use `get`. Is it even necessary that I need the GSI's then?